# function returning function as property

Tags: javascript

I know that it's sometimes handy to make functions return other functions so that you don't have to repeat yourself, increase modularity, etc.
But what's the point in this snippet(one of many) here from the [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Matrix4.js#L445-L467) library?

```
Object.assign( Matrix4.prototype, {

...

    applyToBufferAttribute: function () {

        var v1 = new Vector3();

        return function applyToBufferAttribute( attribute ) {

            for ( var i = 0, l = attribute.count; i < l; i ++ ) {

                v1.x = attribute.getX( i );
                v1.y = attribute.getY( i );
                v1.z = attribute.getZ( i );

                v1.applyMatrix4( this );

                attribute.setXYZ( i, v1.x, v1.y, v1.z );

            }

            return attribute;

        };

    }(),

...

} );
```

The 'inlined' `applyToBufferAttribute` doesn't get reused anywhere else.

Comment: What is: `...`?

Comment: Could just be a developer's style - making your code easily reusable / extendable is a pretty good habit to be in because in theory it makes future development easier.

Comment: If i am reading this right, the `applyToBufferAttribute` method gets set to te function of the same name. The only goal here would be to create a single vector for every execution of this function, but beats me why, as soon as it returns the garbage collector should dispose of local vector if there was to be one.

Comment: @zer00ne placeholders for more code, I didn't want to post the whole file

Comment: @Dellirium: I'd say the point is exactly that - avoiding the garbage collector. Imagine the function gets called a million times a second; that's a lot of allocations and cleanups avoided for the cost of one permanently allocated vector.

Comment: MIght have a point there, never really thought of 'optimizing' the collector itself, merely thought of it as a tool

Comment: @wordorf assuming that the rest of the code isn't relevant, I would have to agree with Amandan is that it's an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) but it's signature is not fully there `(function(){...})();` you're missing the outer parenthesis. Although it's not required, it's strongly suggested that the outer parens be there in order to set to a variable, the value will be the result of said function and not the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned function becomes the method, yes. The purpose of wrapping it into an IIFE is to hide the `v1` variable, making it what C would call "static variable": no matter how many `Matrix4` objects you make, no matter how many times you invoke `applyToBufferAttribute`, there will be only one instance of `v1`, and it will not be accessible except inside the `applyToBufferAttribute` function.

The purpose of *that*, we can only guess at, but probably avoiding allocation and deallocation costs for that `Vector3` object, assuming `applyToBufferAttribute` gets called with some frequency. Given that three.js is a WebGL library, every little bit of optimisation helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you "hide" a variable to the outer scope.

`v1` is no longer visible outside of your module and you make sure that nobody will tamper it.

Typically the return function is a closure that close over the `v1` variable.

An alternative would be to make a full fledge object and make `v1` readonly but you often wont bother to make such object. So it a quick handy way to encapsulate some variable.

A second alternative would be the add `v1` to the return object.

```
function applyToBufferAttribute() {
    if (!this.v1) {
        this.v1 = new Vector3();
    }
    ...
 }
```

But this also have the issue of making `v1` visible outside and make code more fragile.